# Como adicionar :hover corretamento via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando elementos e setando atributos dinamicamente via JavaScript.
Porém não estou conseguindo setar a propriedade `:hover`.

Segue código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
let valores = ['0119621A0','7.6.62.211', '27.1.23.112'];
let cores = ["#0000ff","#00b300","#ff471a"];

if (valores.length != null){
let divPrincial = document.getElementById("kits");

  for(var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let lbl = document.createElement("label");
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    var css = i + ":hover { background-color: #00ff00 }";
    style.styleSheet = css;
    lbl.innerHTML = valores[i];
    div.setAttribute("id",i);
    div.setAttribute('onclick','active(this);');
    div.setAttribute("style","background-color:" + cores[i] + ";" + "border: 2px solid " + cores[i] + ";");
    div.classList.add("t1");
    if(i == 0){
      div.classList.add("active");
    }
    divPrincial.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(lbl);
    div.appendChild(style);
    }
  }
});

function teste(){
  alert();
}

function active(temp){
var element = document.getElementById(temp.id);
var ativo = document.getElementsByClassName('active');  

  element.classList.add("active");

for(var i = 0; i < ativo.length; i++){
  if(ativo[i].id != temp.id){
      document.getElementById(ativo[i].id).classList.remove("active");
     } 
   }
}
```

```css
.vl {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  height: 500px;
   margin-left: 5vw;
}

#kits{
    margin-left: 6.5vw;
    margin-top: -24vw;
}

.t1 {

  margin-left: -26px;
  width: 4.7vw;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 50px;
  height: 2vw;
  

}

label {
    margin-left: 0.2vw;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0.4vw;

}




.active {
width: 5.7vw !important;
}
 .active > label {
 margin-left: 0.5vw;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="vl"></div>

<div id ="kits">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar, seria melhor você usar o JS para adicionar/remover classes, e tratar o `:hover` no código CSS.

Comment: Desta forma que você falou já tinha feito, e funcionou muito bem. Só queria ter certeza algumas possibilidades com o JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando o Jquery a resposta é bem simples como você pode ver utilizando a [função .hover() do Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```js
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
  }
);
 
$( "li.fade" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
  $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
});
```

```css
  ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: blue;
  }
  
  li {
    cursor: default;
  }
  
  span {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hover demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
  <li class="fade">Chips</li>
  <li class="fade">Socks</li>
</ul>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Para adicionar um estilo especial às células da tabela que estão sendo passadas, tente:**

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

**Para desvincular o exemplo acima, use:**

```
$( "td" ).off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );
```

---

Referências:

[Função .hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[Stackoverflow - mouse hover Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126447/mouse-hover-javascript?rq=1)